# responce to multi numbers

Tags: node.js, discord.js

im trying to make a specific responce  for a set of numbers but i dont know the exact code for that for exemple i want the responce for only numbers in between 10 and 15 it doesnt interupt with the other 2 results

```
 module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


var s, final;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() *( 10000)) /500;

 s = random + .005 + '',


    final = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.') + 3);


   message.reply("Your BC Mark is " + final);
   if (final + 16 > 16){

    message.reply(`excellent mark !`)
  }
  if (final + 10 > 15 ){

    message.reply(`good !`)
  }
  if (final + 1 < 10.5) {

    message.reply(`not bad   !`)
  }


}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "bac" 
}
```

Comment: What is the code you’ve provided currently doing or not doing? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @SebastianSimon sorry im new  to this  ive pasted the whole code what im trying is  making the responce  of the second message  differ according to the number result   for exemple if number is less than 10 it says bad if the number is in between 11 and 15 it says good and if more than 15 it says exellent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if your number is greater than or equal to a value and also less than or equal to a value. This would create your intended ranges.

Test the code below and implement it as necessary.

```js
const num = 8;

if (num >= 1 && num <= 5) console.log('Between 1 and 5.');
if (num >= 6 && num <= 10) console.log('Between 6 and 10.');
if (num >= 11 && num <= 15) console.log('Between 11 and 15.');
```

[More about comparison operators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)